# How can we read all cell values from an Excel file using crealytics library

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data from a Excel file like below using crealytics library

`df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("inferschema",False).option("header", False).option("dataAddress","'sheet name'!").load(excel_file_path)`

and it returns a dataframe which considers merged cells as single cells.

my question here is how can we read all cell values?
Is there any option need to enable to return cell values as rows? or do we need to use anyother api to return data instead of DF?

I added a sample screenshot of Excelfile here.

[image]

while reading the data observed that F and G columns from the excel sheet are not returning by data frame. Not able to understand the logic on why it is not returning  if someone can help on it will be greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Merged cells in excel is just cosmetic.
If you do this, you'll understand :

- Create an Excel Sheet
- Put 1 in A1, in A2 and in B2
- Merge A1 and B1
- Sum(A:A) and Sum(B:B) - First one is 2, seconde one is 1.

So your dataframe is just what excel gives.

[image: Excel]

If you want the same value every where, do not use merged cells.

Comment: When reading the above kind of Excel sheet using Crealytics library it does not return a few columns. for example in your screenshot values of the first column i.e SUM. I wanted to understand reason for it